# Simple E-mail test from Ubuntu error - /var/log/mail.log "Connection Refused"

Tags: email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I am trying to send an E-mail to my Gmail inbox from an Ubuntu machine using the simple command

```
USER@MACHINE:~$ echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" RECIPIENT
```

I never receive the E-mail, and the log file at /var/log/mail.log shows some errors that I do not know how to resolve. Can someone offer advice on this? Below is the content of mail.log:

```
USER@MACHINE:~$ echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" RECIPIENT
USER@MACHINE:~$ sudo tail /var/log/mail.log
[sudo] password for USER:
Aug 24 11:00:28 MACHINE postfix/error[4862]: C565E62BF3: to=<RECIPIENT>, relay=none, delay=949, delays=949/0.08/0/0.03, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM [64.233.186.27]:25: Connection refused)
Aug 24 11:06:24 MACHINE postfix/pickup[4749]: 9179D62BF5: uid=1000 from=<USER>
Aug 24 11:06:24 MACHINE postfix/cleanup[4868]: 9179D62BF5: message-id=<20170824160624.9179D62BF5@MACHINE>
Aug 24 11:06:24 MACHINE postfix/qmgr[4750]: 9179D62BF5: from=<USER@SUB.DOMAIN.NET>, size=335, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 24 11:06:25 MACHINE postfix/smtp[4870]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[2607:f8b0:4002:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Aug 24 11:06:25 MACHINE postfix/smtp[4870]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.21.26]:25: Connection refused
Aug 24 11:06:25 MACHINE postfix/smtp[4870]: connect to ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[64.233.190.27]:25: Connection refused
Aug 24 11:06:25 MACHINE postfix/smtp[4870]: connect to ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[173.194.210.27]:25: Connection refused
Aug 24 11:06:25 MACHINE postfix/smtp[4870]: connect to ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[2800:3f0:4003:c01::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Aug 24 11:06:25 MACHINE postfix/smtp[4870]: 9179D62BF5: to=<RECIPIENT>, relay=none, delay=1.2, delays=0.11/0.05/1/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[2800:3f0:4003:c01::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

Comment: Are you sending this from your own device? Many ISPs block port 25 to prevent spam.

Comment: @Ryan I am trying to send the E-mail from my own machine, yes